# Finding number of shutdown guests on a host - Openstack

Tags: bash, openstack, openstack-nova

I am trying to figure out how many shutdown guests (or tenants) there are on a host versus the total number of guests on a host. I'm able to hard-code it using `nova list`, `grep` and `wc -l` but I was wondering if there are any flags or cleaner ways of getting this information.

Thanks

Comment: Which version of openstack?  Also, I don't have a handy place to test, but you could probably use the `--status ` flag to restrict them only those with the status you care about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested these commands in OpenStack Newton.

You can list all the shutdown guests by running the below command

```
nova list --status SHUTOFF
```

If you want to list shutdown guests on a compute node, find the compute hostname and use the name with --host argument

```
nova host-list
nova list --host compute1 --status SHUTOFF
```